# Override values of Subcharts inHelm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

We have created common helm charts. 
Using the common charts, we have derived HelloWorld helm chart

```
Charts
  Common
    templates
      > _deployment.yaml
      > _configmap.yaml
      > _service.yaml
    Chart.yaml

  HelloWorld
    templates
      > deployment.yaml 
      > configmap.yaml
      > service.yaml
    Chart.yaml
    values.yaml 
    values-dev.yaml
```

We wanted to override values specified values.yaml (subchart) using values-dev.yaml , We understand we can override the values from the subchart.
The values can be overrided.

However, we wanted to override the values for chart level instead of app level. Below is the structure.

```
Charts
  Common
    templates
      > _deployment.yaml
      > _configmap.yaml
      > _service.yaml
    Chart.yaml

  HelloWorld1
    templates
      > deployment.yaml 
      > configmap.yaml
      > service.yaml
    Chart.yaml
    values-HelloWorld1.yaml 
    values-dev.yaml 

    HelloWorld2
      templates
        > deployment.yaml   
        > configmap.yaml
        > service.yaml
      Chart.yaml
      values-HelloWorld2.yaml   
      values-qa.yaml    

values.yaml
```

Is it possible to override the values from values.yaml?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but in general you can override subchart values at any point by putting them under a key matching the charts name. So something like:

```
Common:
  foo: bar
```

Comment: @SunilGajula Is `Common` a subchart folder in your parent chart (or in requirements.yaml). Because, the above works for me.

Comment: @SaikiranYerram, Common folder is a parent project. HelloWorld1 and HelloWorld2 are the sub-projects. Please Note, values.yaml is placed in the charts folder level.